# How do I handle these events and why is my code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to do the following. As soon as the user clicks on a div, i want to save the mouse coordinations while the user is moving the cursor over the div and is holding the left mouse button. When the user leaves the div or releases the left button, i want to stop recording the coordinates. I've got the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var coordhdl = new coordinateHandler();
            $("#test").mousedown(function(e) {

                $("#test").mousemove(function(ee) {
                    
                    $("#test").mouseup(function(e) {
                        stopIt = true;
                    });
                    if(stopIt == false)
                    {
                        coordhdl.addCords(ee.pageX - this.offsetLeft, ee.pageY - this.offsetTop);
                    }
                    
                
                });
    
            }); 
            
            
        });
```

The problems with this code are:

- It records coordinate even when the user only clicked the div without pressing the left button.
- It doesn't stop recording the coordinates once it has been clicked.

I am new to Javascript/jQuery, so I don't know very much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. It sets a flag to true/false when the mouse is pressed/released respectively. When the mouse moves, if the flag is set, the coordinates are added:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isDown = false,
        coordhdl = new coordinateHandler();
    $("#test").mousedown(function() {
       isDown = true;
    }).mouseup(function() {
       isDown = false;  
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(isDown) {
            coordhdl.addCords(ee.pageX - this.offsetLeft, ee.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/3wEwp/) of something similar in action (it simply writes the coordinates to a `p` element instead of using your `coordinateHandler` object).

Comment: for some reasons this doesn't work for me. And so do the other 2 answers here. It doesn't stop recording when i release the button. Did you test this code? Maybe the problem is my browser. I'm using IE 8

Comment: @Luke - Yes, I tested it in the link I posted in the answer. Have a look at that and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't attach the event handlers inside the event handlers. On every mouse move you attach a new `mouseup` event handler. They don't get overridden, they get appended.

Use a "global" flag instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var coordhdl = new coordinateHandler(),
        recording = false;

    $("#test").mousedown(function(e) {
        recording = true;
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(recording) {
            coordhdl.addCords(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        }
    }).mouseup(function(e) {
        recording = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time there is a `mousedown` event, you add a `mousemove` handler, and every time the mouse moves, you add another `mouseup` handler. I can't see where the `stopIt` variable is declared so the scope of this variable may also be an issue. You don't need to nest the handlers, so try it this way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var coordhdl = new coordinateHandler();
        var isRecording = false;
        $("#test").mousedown(function(e) { isRecording = true })
                  .mouseup(function(e) { isRecording = false })
                  .mousemove(function(ee) {
                     if(isRecording)
                     {
                         coordhdl.addCords(ee.pageX - this.offsetLeft, ee.pageY - this.offsetTop);
                     }
                  });
    });
```